# output of php file is saved in a text file

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

Need to print a file content in a page and store those result in text file as downloadable format
I have wrote a Php script for displaying file content 
Form is given below

```
<form action="newfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" maxlength="25"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
```

Php script is

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$result = file_get_contents($file);
print $result;
```

it will print the file content but how can I store its result in .txt file format and how can I downloaded or saved it in our machine

Please provide me a solution for saving result of it in .txt format

Comment: [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to use the file functions like following:**

example:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'hello my name is george');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Description can be found here:**

http://php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php

Comment: it will take the content you insert - fwrite($fp, $result);

Answer (score 0):

Use `readfile()`

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo readfile($file);
```

**EDIT 01**

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("my file.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "John Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

    //move_uploaded_file(file,newlocation)
    $tmp_name = $myfile["tmp_name"][$key];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,'./folder/')
?>
```

Comment: I want to store its result in a text file along with  I need to store it in a folder

Comment: you want to write in file?? and what is it??

Comment: I want to browse  a file and its content is stored in a .text file and it is stored in our machine also

Comment: Thanks for your reply,,, but I need to browse a file and display its content ...for doing these I have wrote a PHP script and it is working properly . Now I need to display file content in a text file and it is stored in /home/user/Documents

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    <?php
        $file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $result = file_get_contents($file);

        $write_text_file = fopen("path/to/result.txt", "w");
        fwrite($write_text_file, $result);
        fclose($write_text_file);
    ?>
```

Comment: it does not giving any output